# i am looking for a simple model (like a tree) to generate new data from an input dataset

Tags: tree, lstm, prediction

i am looking for a simple model (like a tree) to generate new data from an input dataset, i m using LSTM as 'complex model' and i generate new data.

Now i need to a find a simple model ( preferible tree regressor) to generate new value from an input db.

This is the datasdet: https://data.world/prolis/simulation-log-of-loan-business-process

I found online compact precision tree but this model  i think work only on string data to generate more sequence.

Did you know any model that can help me?

This is the probem explained more simple:

Db_first ( A B C D)  -> application of tree regressor for prediction -> new db ( A B C D)

Comment: Do you have any specifics about which programming language or libraries you want to use? This might be more suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ if it's not related to programming in some way.

Comment: python as program language and library i think keras or sklearn  would be fine